# Socket IO broadcasting to room is not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, pug, mean-stack

If this is a vague question, please let me know, so that I can specify. I really want to get around this stump.

I have read several cheat sheets regarding how to properly broadcast a message to a client room. My reference is: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md.

To describe my problem: 
The chat page comes up with the send button correctly, however as soon as I click send, nothing is ever sent.

The interesting thing, is that whenever I am not using rooms, and just use the default namespace, I can get messages.

Any idea on what is going on? Thank you!!

**server.js**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    global.rooms = 'room1';
    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
        socket.join(rooms);
        console.log(socket.id + 'joining room', rooms)
    })
    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
        io.to(rooms).emit('chat', data);
  })
})
```

**chat.jade**

```
extends layout

block content

 h2.page-header Chat Page
 div(id='the-chat')
  div(id='chat-window')
   div(id='output')
  input(id='handle', type='text', value = user.name, style= 'width: 0px; visibility: hidden;')
  input(id='message', type='text', placeholder='message')
  button(id='send' value='Send') Send

  //imports the socket.io functionality on the client side for the chat.jade application
  script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")

  script.

    //variable created that mirrors connection made in the backend

    //matches the connection made in the server side
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000')

    //Query dom
    var message = document.getElementById('message')
    var handle = document.getElementById('handle')
    var btn = document.getElementById('send')
    var output = document.getElementById('output')

    //emit events
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
      })
    })


    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
      output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
      document.getElementById('message').value = "";
    })
```

**Home.jade**

```
extends layout


block content

    h2.page-header(style = "text-align: center;").
        Home Page

    if (user.isTutor)
        b(style = "text-align: center;")
            form(method='post', action = '/home/available')
                input.btn.btn-primary(type = 'submit',name='isAvailable', value = 'Available', id = 'button4')
            form(method='post', action = '/home/unavailable')
                input.btn.btn-primary(type = 'submit',name='isUnavailable', value = 'Unavailable', id = 'button5')  
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script.
        var btn = document.getElementById('button4')
        //var space = '#{user.room}'
        var socket = io.connect()
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            socket.emit('subscribe', 'room1')
        })

    div(id = 'magic')
        form(method='get')
            if (user.hasApplied)
                input.btn.btn-primary(type = 'submit', onclick = "javascript: form.action = '/findatutor';" name='find', value = 'Find a Tutor', class = 'middle', id = 'button7')

            else if (user.hasApplied == false)
                input.btn.btn-primary(type = 'submit', onclick = "javascript: form.action = '/findatutor';" name='find', value = 'Find a Tutor', id = 'button1')
                input.btn.btn-primary(type = 'submit', onclick = "javascript: form.action = '/apply';"  name='become', value = 'Become a Tutor', id = 'button2')
```

**Home.js**

```
router.post('/available', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res,next) => {
    var io = res.locals['socketio']
    db.collection('DefaultUser').update({_id: req.user._id}, {$set: {isAvailable: true}});
    res.redirect('../chat')
})
```

Comment: Is any one in that room to receive the message? I am not seeing anywhere in chat.jade where you are emitting the 'subscribe' event to the server so that you join the room. Is that emit event in a different area of the application?

Comment: The event emitter has been included above in the home.jade button. 2 things should happen when the user clicks the 'available' button which has an id = button4. Number One: They should be redirected to the chat.jade and Number Two: They should emit a subscribe event for room1. If it is at all helpful, I console.log(data) on the server side, and get the correct data every time I click submit. The problem is that the information fails to broadcast on the client side. Here is the cmd results: { message: 'hi', handle: 'William Sheppard' }  @JamesPooley

Comment: I have also provided a snippet of my home.js file that contains a post request for the 'available' route that represents the button that will (1) redirect to the chat page and (2) initiate the connection to room1 @JamesPooley

Comment: Double check me on this. When you navigate from home.jade to chat.jade, dont you get disconnected and reconnect to the socket? From what I know, this would create a new socket object instance on the server, meaning the new socket  would NOT be subscribed/in the room since its a new instance of socket. Try testing by emitting the subscribe event to the server within the chat.jade script just see if it works that way.

chat.jade
    `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000')
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('subscribe', 'room1')
    })` then try chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you did not specify where to render the messages. As I understood, you have no problem creating rooms, so I will explain step by step how to handle after that point.

According to your code this is the communication between server and client for sending messages

```
//server.js
 socket.on('chat', function(data) {
        io.to(rooms).emit('chat', data);
  })
//chat.jade
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
      })
    })
```

First client is sending the message (typing the input box) to the server and when server receives it, it has to send the same message to all other clients. once clients receive this message, clients have to figure out how to display it. But when server sends the received message, then you have to initiate a new event. let's call it display. so your code should be like this:

```
//server.js
//i always use arrow functions, but I will follow along your code
     socket.on('chat', function(data) { 
            io.to(rooms).emit('display', data);
      })
```

Now your client should be listening for this event and should be handling where to display it:

//chat.jade

```
socket.on('display', (data) => {
    const displayedMessage = pug.render(messageTemplate, {
        message: data.message,
    })
    $messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', displayedMessage)
})
```

Since Jade has been renamed to pug, i used pug here. So i will render {message: data.message} into html in a script tag then placed it into DOM ELEMENT $message.

I am not sure where you want to render `handle:handle.value` i will just show how to display message. similarly, you can handle it.

Now what are `messageTemplate`, `$messages` and insertAdjacentHTML()?

create a div tag and a script tag in your html

```
//this is where you are gonna display the message
<div id="messages" class="chat__messages"></div>

<!-- template messages -->
    <script id="message-template" type="text/html">
      <div>
          <p>{{message}}</p>
      </div>
    </script>
```

//chat.jade

```
const $messages = document.getElementById("messages");
const messageTemplate = document.getElementById("message-template").innerHTML;
```

The insertAdjacentHTML() method inserts a text as HTML, into a specified position. you can get more explanation and examples here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacenthtml.asp

socket io code looks long and complicated but if you know the logic and move step by step it will easy to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
io.in(rooms).emit('chat', data);
```

Comment: I tried this out, with no success. I included a "console.log(data)" right after the line you just recommended above and I get: { message: 'this is example text', handle: 'Bob Peterson' }  @kevin

Comment: So essentially, the message is being captured correctly, however it is not being broadcast to the room.

Answer (score 0):

Missing this under `global.rooms = 'room1';`

```
var rooms = global.rooms
```

Longer Answer: At least what I can see, you've added "rooms" as a property on the global object (idk where 'global' itself is defined, but if it's not throwing an error, I'm assuming you defined it above). While it's a property, the variable 'rooms' that you're using as a namespace isn't defined at the time you're calling it, so it doesn't know where to emit the message.

Even more answer: Also, if you're intending to add additional rooms to global.rooms, I think you might want to use a hashlist to store them, so that you can easily access them as `global.rooms[room]`, as well as easily add new rooms to the list ie `global.rooms[room.name] = room`

Comment: Hm you would think his server would be throwing an undefined error too though? I wonder if rooms is defined again somewhere up above as well.

Comment: Not necessarily. Try this in your console: x = ""; x.charAt(undefined);

He's using it as a value, not accessing any properties/functions on it.